# Colocar como pattern valores com duas casas decimais em input html5

Tags: html5

Tenho uma input numérica, e gostaria que nela só fosse válido pelo pattern, valores com .xx  (ponto mais duas casas decimais).

Meu código:

```
<div>
    <label for="valorTr> Valor: </label>
    <input type="number" pattern=" " id="valorTransf" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O atributo `pattern` só funciona em `types`: `text`, `search`, `tel`, `url`, `email`, ou `password`. Não funciona em `type="number"`. ([Veja documentação MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-pattern))

Para validar o campo usando regex, você poderá fazer via JavaScript usando `match`:

```js
$("#valorTransf").blur(function(){
   
   var valor = $(this).val();
   
   if(valor.match(/^\.\d{2}\b/)){
      console.log("ok");
   }else{
      console.log("inválido");
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="valorTr"> Valor: </label>
<input type="number" id="valorTransf" />
```

Onde a regex:

```
^\.\d{2}\b/

^\.    -> deverá iniciar com um ponto
\d{2}  -> deverá ter 2 dígitos após o ponto
\b     -> metacharacter que delimita o início (ou fim).
          Significa que não pode ter mais que 2 dígitos após o ponto
```